# Error creating realRatingMatrix per not defined class

Tags: r

I'm attempting to set up my dataset to to work with [package recommenderlab](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/index.html).  It requires the dataset be `realRatingMatrix` or `binaryRatingMatrix`.  When I attempt to create it from a sparse matrix I get the following error.  Please help.

```
c <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5)
p <- c(1,2,3,2,4,1,1,2,3,3)
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(c,p,x)

sparse_data <- sparseMatrix(i = df$product,
                         j = df$client,
                         x = df$link,
                         dims = c(length(unique(df$product_id)), length(unique(df$client_id))),  
                         dimnames = list(paste("p", 1:length(unique(df$product_id)), sep = ""), 
                                         paste("c", 1:length(unique(df$client_id)), sep = "")))
sparse_data[1:4, 1:4]
rec_dataset <- new("realRatingMatrix", data = sparse_data)
```

The last line gives me the following error:

> ```
>     Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
>     “realRatingMatrix” is not a defined class
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Once run library(recommenderlab) and then execute the command:

```
rec_dataset <- new("realRatingMatrix", data = sparse_data)
```

It did work for me.